# Getting authorization error while pushing selenium webdriver code to Bitbucket

Tags: eclipse, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, bitbucket

While i'm trying to push my selenium code to bitbucket using "EGit - Git integration for Eclipse 5.4.0", getting the below authorization error,

```
Error Detail:
https://name@bitbucket.org/name/testing.git: not authorized
https://name@bitbucket.org/name/testing.git: not authorized
```

I have my company account and my account is registered with company email which is managed by Google , eventhough I have provided correct credentials I'm getting this authorization error . I have tried giving many different combinations but getting into the same error.

Can anyone please tell me what is wrong with it, Is there any settings i have missed out or any other things i need to do to overcome this error and push the code to Bitbucket.

Attached the image of the error for reference, if anyone can guide me on this,will be much grateful.

Thanks in advance!!

Comment: Perhaps you should try using an SSH remote URL instead of an HTTP URL? Typically authorization will happen using SSH keys which won't work if you clone the repository using the HTTP URL.

Comment: This may be plugin issue. Have you tried with git bash console or git GUI?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's a support query for OP's company Helpdesk.